# Tectite formmail php script error when migrating to https://

Tags: php, https, formmail

Tectite formmail gives an error when migrating to https://

After submitting the form, the browser goes to:

```
https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/templates/HB-home/forms/fmbadhandler.php?insession=1&vuyk=790dg132pl9sm33qcla6ho7dn5
```

And gives a white page with this message:

```
"insession specified, but no data found in session "
```

I receive a mail with subject "FormMail script error" and the message:

> mail_failed  ********** Error=Failed to send email

Plus a mail with subject "FormMail script error" and the message:

> Socket error 0: :

When testing with https://www.harrieboerhof/templates/HB-home/forms/formmail-aanvraag-tuinontwerpgesprek.php?testalert=1 in the browser a message:

> Test message sent. Check your email.

and a mail is received with:

> > This is a test alert message  Loaded language is English (builtin) PHP version is 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 FormMail version is 8.24 Server
> >     type: non-Windows
>
> DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/testhtml SCRIPT_FILENAME:
>   /var/www/testhtml/templates/HB-home/forms/formmail-zend-uw-bericht-test.php
>   PATH_TRANSLATED: -not set- REAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www
>
> SERVER_NAME was localhost REQUEST_URI was
>   /templates/HB-home/forms/formmail-zend-uw-bericht-test.php?testalert=1
>
> User IP address was 81.206.125.28 User agent was Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0

The html of the form:

```html
<form action="https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/templates/HB-home/forms/formmail-zend-uw-bericht-test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input name="recipients" type="hidden" value="harrie" >
  <input type="hidden" name="bcc" value="mail@domain.nl" />
  <input name="conditions" type="hidden" value="conditions" >
  <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="Contactformulier van website" >
  <input name="mail_options" type="hidden" value="HTMLTemplate=https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/templates/HB-home/forms/zend-ons-uw-bericht.htm, NoPlain, FromAddr=noreply@harrieboerhof.nl,TemplateMissing=-, CharSet=utf-8 " >
  <input name="good_url" type="hidden" value="https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/nl/zend-ons-uw-bericht-bedankt/" >
  <input name="bad_url" type="hidden" value="https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/templates/HB-home/forms/fmbadhandler.php" >
  <input name="this_form" type="hidden" value="https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/nl/contact-met-uw-tuinman-hovenier-uit-drenthe/contactformulier/" />
  <input name="bad_template" type="hidden" value="https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/nl/onvolledige-contactaanvraag/" />
```

When I use the http:// version of the testsite, everything works fine.
I searched Google for this condition, but it seems to be the first time this happens, I hope someone has an idea what could be wrong?

Edit: the accepted answer is not quite the answer, look in the comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that PHP sessions are not working as they should with your https://test site.

"vuyk" appears to be the session name.

So do you have

`$SESSION_NAME = "vuyk";`

in both FormMail and FMBadHandler?

If so, then it may be a problem with the configuration of sessions for your https://test site.

Comment: Yes, $SESSION_NAME is set to "vuyk" in both files. The strange thing is that when testing with http:// everything works fine.
I have made a phpinfo() on https://test.harrieboerhof.nl/info.php

Comment: OK, we'll take this offline and work on it directly.

Comment: **Findings and solution**: the root cause was the setting of TEMPLATEURL combined with the configuration of nginx.  The "Socket" error was caused by FormMail trying to access the email template, and that was failing because the TEMPLATEURL setting was "https://localhost".  Nginx was not configured for SSL access to localhost and this caused the failure to load the template.  FormMail then sent the "Failed to send email" alert message as a consequence of the failure to open the template.  The session errors were not relevant to the actual problem.

Comment: The message "insession specified, but no data found in session" disappeared after upgrading the script to the last version which was better accomodated to php7